# AngularJS cannot find template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my directive

```
(function() {
    angular.module('commentsDirective', [])

    .directive('mngComments', mngComments)

    function mngComments() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                moment: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'comments.html',
            replace: true,
            controller: 'CommentsController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        };
    };
})();
```

Here is my file structure:

[image]

And I get this error message:

[image]

I'm not understanding this.  My html file is in the same directory as my directive so why can't it find it?

Comment: you need to specify the relative path like this  ```./comments.html```

Comment: I've tried that - I got the same error message

Comment: Instead of having a separate function, will it work with the normal construction? .directive('mngComments', function() { }) etc... (and like Bogdan says, relative path too)

Comment: The path is probably relative to the HTML page and not the directive location. So whatever path you prepend to load the directive should be used in the directive to load the template.

Comment: directive script location is irrelevant. Browser works off of page relative location

Comment: Please set template path as relative in where it is added not according js and template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path to template should be relative to page’s path. So if directory comments is placed at root, you should specify templateUrl as /comments/comments.html.

If you want to use your module in unknown paths, you can use $templateCache to “import” your template to your module first. Then you can specify custom URL used while defining templateCache.